# How do you make sbt `test` equivalent to a run command with some set of options?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm working on a project where the standard method to run some test, `foo`, is to do `run foo --bar --baz --qux --quux someDirectory`. Worse still, documentation is pretty thin, and it took some digging around to figure out that was how tests are run.

The reason this is the case is that the project does some code generation (it generates c++, which then gets compiled and run), and the test is to run the generated code vs. a model that's also a blob of generated code that's produced by the same project. Looking at it from that perspective, you can see how things came to be this way, but it makes running tests unintuitive.

I'd like to be able to run tests with `test foo`. Is it possible to make `test foo` simply execute the above run command, and, if so, how do I do it?

If it's not possible, I'll add some documentation so newcomers to project can figure things out more easily. But, I'd prefer to make things consistent with other projects that use sbt.

Comment: Is the intention for `test foo` to expand to `run foo --bar ...` or was that just a shorthand and you still expect the full `test foo --bar ...`?

Comment: The former -- I would like to, by default, expand to the full list. But, it would be nice to specify options to test that allow "advanced" users to choose something besides the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this currently is to directly implement a custom task.  See [Input Tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Input-Tasks.html) for details.

```
// A custom task is required because `test` doesn't accept input.
lazy val customTest = inputKey[Unit]("custom test")

// This custom parser accepts a space separated list of arguments and then appends
//   the fixed arguments to them.  To do further parsing based on the user-specified
//   arguments, use `flatMap` and return the next Parser.
lazy val testParser =
   Def.spaceDelimited().map( (explicitArgs: Seq[String]) =>
      explicitArgs ++ Seq("--bar", "--baz", "--qux", "--quux", "someDirectory")
   )

customTest := {
   // the result of parsing
   val args = testParser.parsed
   // auto-detected main class: can replace with literal string
   val main = (mainClass in Compile).value getOrElse error("No main class detected.")
   // main classpath, including compiled classes
   val classpath = (fullClasspath in Compile).value.files
   // provides Scala code execution
   val scalaRun = (runner in (Compile, run)).value
   val result = scalaRun.run(main, classpath, args, streams.value.log)
   // handle any error
   result foreach { errorMsg => sys.error(errorMsg) }
}
```